# CircleCI Docker Exited with code 137

Tags: docker, circleci

I'm using `- image: peopleperhour/dynamodb` for a docker image in my CircleCI config file.

In CircleCI it's outputting the following.

```
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:   false
DbPath: /var/dynamodb_local
SharedDb:   false
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams: *


Exited with code 137
```

The first tests pass fine and `Exited with code 137` doesn't happen until later on. But once that error happens all the tests start failing.

I saw [this](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/using-official-docker-images/13196/2) link and changed my code to the following with no luck.

```
  - image: peopleperhour/dynamodb
    environment:
        MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 2048m
        HEAP_NEWSIZE: 512m
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: error code 137 is due to running out of memory. Can you monitor memory usage while running and run `dmesg` once your container crashes?

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same thing in my builds using Amazon's dynamodb-local container.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. I ended up just using localstack for it, as the memory footprint seems to be lower.

My config for that container looks like:

```
- image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      SERVICES: dynamodb:4570
      DEFAULT_REGION: us-west-2
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try to specify a restart policy for the container:

```
- image: peopleperhour/dynamodb
  restart: on-failure # Restart the container if it exits due to an error
  environment:
    MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 2048m
    HEAP_NEWSIZE: 512m
```

Comment: Same problem, this doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @CharlieFish can you provide container logs `docker container logs <container-name>`?

Comment: I can just add that as the last step to my configuration file correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try 3 other things.

1:

Add resource limits to your docker section of the config.yml
resources:

```
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
            limits:
              memory: "4Gi"
```

The default resource is Medium with 2 vCPUs and 4GB of ram.

2:

Use Java option environment vars to set memory limits.
https://circleci.com/blog/how-to-handle-java-oom-errors/

3:

If you are using a non-basic account you can tell Circleci to use a different machine resource_class. You have to have the performance plan for this.
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#resource_class

Answer (score 0):

I use the `amazon/dynamodb-local` container to start DynamoDB local on CircleCI. I was having the same issue and setting `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` and Java options through the container wasn't really working for me, either. I found that the best way to do this was to override the entry-point for the container:

```
docker:
- image: amazon/dynamodb-local:1.13.1
  entrypoint: java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -Xmx256m -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -port 8000
```